# How to add a personalized input to a specified row and column in google sheets using google script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am a begginer in javascript/google apps script and I need help..
[google sheets extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kySvG.png)

I would like for the user to be able to type in the type of the piece (0511 for example) and the number of defaults it has (2 for example) and then it will be filled automatically in the right cell from the right row (the row of the type written) and the right column (active column)

Here is what I already wrote (it allows me to fill in the 4 firsts rows of the active cell) :

This is in form.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myform">

    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input type='date' name='date' id="date" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="reference">Référence</label>
    <input type='text' name='reference' id="reference" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="qtebonne">Quantité bonne</label>
    <input type='text' name='qtebonne' id="qtebonne" required="required"/>
    </div>


    <div class="block">
    <table>
    <col width="60">

   <tr>
          <th><strong></strong></th>
          <th><strong>M</strong></th>
          <th><strong>AM  </strong></th>
          <th><strong> N</strong></th>
          <th><strong>WE</strong></th>
   </tr>  

   <tr>
    <td>Equipe</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="equipe" value="M" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="equipe" value="AM"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="equipe" value="N"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="equipe" value="WE"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>


      <div class="block">  
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data()"/>
      <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()"/>
    </div> 



    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>


    </form>


        <script>
    document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", 
    function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
    google.script.run.addNewItem(this);
     google.script.host.close();//close this dialogbox
    }
    );

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

This is in code.gs :

```
function onOpen() 
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Remplissage')
  .addItem('Ajout Item', 'addItem')
      .addToUi();
}

function addItem()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Ajout Nouvel Item');

}



function addNewItem(form_data)
{  

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //sheet.insertColumnAfter(sheet.getLastColumn());


  var cellA = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  cellA.setValue([form_data.date]);

  var cellB = cellA.offset(1, 0); //+1 pour la ligne en dessous
  cellB.setValue([form_data.reference]);

  var cellC = cellB.offset(1, 0); //+2 pour la ligne encore en dessous
  cellC.setValue([form_data.qtebonne]);


  var cellD = cellC.offset(1, 0); //+3 pour la ligne encore en dessous
  cellD.setValue([form_data.equipe]);


}
```

Here is what it looks like on Excel :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2373.png)

Comment: Hello @Marion! I'm not sure I completely understood your question - so you are basically trying to insert values in `BO column` corresponding to the values from the `D column`?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering :) I am trying to insert values that the user has filled from the pop-up box in the last column, on the row corresponding to the value of the column D that the user has filled too!

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, I tried inserting images but I can't, if you want I can send you if I can :/

Comment: Hey @Marion you can edit your question and insert the images there :) Cheers!

Comment: Hello @MarionVlr can you include a sanitized copy of your spreadsheet at least? Cheers!

Comment: Hello,
Thank you all for your help but a friend of mine helped me so it's done, here is the code if you want :

Answer (score 1):

In form.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myform">



    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input type='date' name='date' id="date" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="reference">Référence</label>
    <input type='text' name='reference' id="reference" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="type">Code rebut</label>
    <input type='text' name='type' id="type" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="qtebonne">Quantité bonne</label>
    <input type='number' name='qtebonne' id="qtebonne" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="qte_rebut">Quantité rebut</label>
    <input type='number' name='qte_rebut' id="qte_rebut" required="required"/>
    </div>



    <div class="block">
    <table>
    <col width="60">

   <tr>
          <th><strong></strong></th>
          <th><strong>M</strong></th>
          <th><strong>AM  </strong></th>
          <th><strong>N</strong></th>
          <th><strong>WE</strong></th>
   </tr>  

   <tr>
    <td>Equipe</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="equipe" value="M" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="equipe" value="AM"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="equipe" value="N"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="equipe" value="WE"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>


    <div class="block">  
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="action" id="Submit"/>
      <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()"/>
      <INPUT type="reset" value="Reset">
    </div> 



    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>


    </form>


    <script>
    document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", 
    function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
      google.script.run.addNewItem(this);
   //   google.script.host.close();//close this dialogbox

    });



 /*   function clearForm() {
  document.getElementById('date').value = "";
  document.getElementById('reference').value = "";
  document.getElementById('type').value = "";
  document.getElementById('qtebonne').value = "";
  document.getElementById('type').value = "";
  document.getElementById('qte_rebut').value = "";
}

    document.getElementById("SubmitAndContinueInput").addEventListener("click", myFunctionContinue);

    function myFunctionContinue(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var obj = document.getElementById("CheckDetailsForm");
  var x = document.getElementById("vendor-selector").value;
  document.getElementById("CompanyName").innerHTML = x;
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(clearForm)
    .functionToRunOnFormSubmit(obj);
}


    document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("SubmitAndContinueInput", 
    function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
      google.script.run.addNewItem(this);
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(clearForm)

    }); */



    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

In code.gs :

```
function onOpen() 
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Remplissage')
  .addItem('Ajout Item', 'addItem')
      .addToUi();
}

function addItem()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form').setHeight(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Ajout Nouvel Item');
  }



function addNewItem(form_data)
{  

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // On détecte la dernière colonne
  var lastColumn = detectLastColumn();

  Logger.log(form_data);

  // On récupère les quatre premières cellules de la dernière colonne
  var header = sheet.getRange(1, lastColumn, 4, 1);




  // Parce que on form_data.date a la forme yyyy-mm-dd donc :
  // split('-') donne une liste ['yyyy', 'mm', 'dd']
  // reverse() donne ['dd', 'mm', 'yyyy']
  // join('/') donne dd/mm/yyyy comme on veut :)
  var formattedDate = form_data.date.split('-').reverse().join('/');

  $today = new Date();
  $yesterday = new Date($today);
  $yesterday.setDate($today.getDate() - 1);

  var $dd = $yesterday.getDate();
  var $mm = $yesterday.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var $yyyy = $yesterday.getFullYear();

  if($dd<10){$dd='0'+$dd} if($mm<10){$mm='0'+$mm} 
  $yesterday = $dd+'/'+$mm+'/'+$yyyy;




  // On y ajoute directement les 4 valeurs voulues dans l'ordre
  var data = [[formattedDate], [form_data.reference], [form_data.qtebonne], [form_data.equipe]];
  header.setValues(data);




  Logger.log(form_data.type);

  var typeRows = findTypeRanges(form_data.type)
  Logger.log(typeRows);

  for (var i = 0; i < typeRows.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('rowindex: ' + typeRows[i])
    sheet.getRange(typeRows[i], lastColumn).setValue(form_data.qte_rebut)
  }
}

// Fonction qui va rechercher toutes les lignes correspondant au type passé en argument
function findTypeRanges(type) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var firstRow = 7 // première ligne à laquelle commence les trucs
  var typeCol = 4 // colonne des types

  var lastRow = detectLastRow(firstRow, typeCol);
  var typesRange = sheet.getRange(firstRow, typeCol, lastRow - firstRow + 1, 1);

  // D'après la doc ça permet de chercher dans une range
  var textFinder = typesRange.createTextFinder(type);
  var allOccurences = textFinder.findAll(); // Chercher toutes occurences

   return allOccurences.map(function (range) {
      return range.getRow(); // Transforme toutes les ranges en juste la ligne
   });
}

// Fonction pour détecter la dernière colonne remplie
function detectLastColumn() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var content = sheet.getRange('F1').getDisplayValue();

  var col = 6; // Parce que la colonne qui nous interesse commence à 'F'
  while (content !== '') {
    col++;
    content = sheet.getRange(1, col).getDisplayValue();
  }
  Logger.log('Last Column: ' + col)

  return col;
}

function detectLastRow(firstRow, typeColumn) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var content = sheet.getRange(firstRow, typeColumn).getDisplayValue();

  var row = firstRow; 
  while (content !== '') {
    row++;
    content = sheet.getRange(row, typeColumn).getDisplayValue();
  }

  Logger.log('Last Row: ' + row); 

  return row;
}
```